# Viewing objects and printing details

Tags: c#, oop

I have got a program to make 3 accounts, savings account, debit card account, and a credit card account.
After having an object made in the main program, i want to have the user display the accounts that were made.

**Account.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Bank
{
    public abstract class Account{


        protected string _type;
        protected int _initbal;


        public Account(string type, int initbal){

            _type=type;
            _initbal=initbal;

        }

        public virtual int Deposit(int amount_depo){

            if(amount_depo<0){
                Console.WriteLine("Amount must be more than 0");
            }

            else{
                _initbal=amount_depo+_initbal;

            }

            return _initbal;


        }
        public virtual int Withdraw(int amount_with){

            if(_initbal<amount_with){
                Console.WriteLine("Insufficient funds");
            }

            else if(amount_with<0){
                Console.WriteLine("Amount must be more than 0");

            }

            else{

                _initbal=amount_with-_initbal;
            }

            return _initbal;

        }

        public abstract void Display();
    }

}
```

**SavingsAccount.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Bank
{
    public class Saving:Account{

        public int _number{get;}

        private static int Number=160140000;
        public Saving(string type, int initbal):base(type,initbal){ 

            Number++;
            _number=Number;
        }

        public override void Display(){

            Console.WriteLine("Account number: " + _number);
            Console.WriteLine("Account type: " + base._type);
            Console.WriteLine("Balance: RM" + base._initbal);


        }

   }
}
```

**DebitAccount.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Bank
{
    public class Debit:Saving{

        public int cardnum{get;}

        private static int Number=46360000;
        public Debit(string type, int initbal):base(type,initbal){

            Number++;
            cardnum=Number;
         }

        public override void Display(){

            Console.WriteLine("Card Number: " + cardnum);
            Console.WriteLine("Current balance: RM" + base._initbal);

        }

   }
}
```

**CreditAccount.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Bank
{
    public class Credit{

        public int cardnum{get;}

        private static int Number=52110000;
        public int _limit {get;}
        private static int Limit=5000;
        private string _type;
        public Credit(string type){ 
            _type=type;
            _limit=Limit;
            Number++;
            cardnum=Number;
        }

        public void Withdraw(int cred_amount_with){

            if(cred_amount_with > _limit){
                Console.WriteLine("Withdrawal limit exceeded!");

            }

            else if(cred_amount_with < 0){
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid, must be more than 0!");

            }

            else{

                Console.WriteLine("Transaction success (from credit card)");
            }



        }

        public void Display(){

            Console.WriteLine("Card Number: " + cardnum);
            Console.WriteLine("Current credit limit: RM" + _limit);


        }


   }
}
```

And my **Main** program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;  

namespace Bank
{
    Console.WriteLine("1.Make new saving/debit/credit account");
    Console.WriteLine("2.Delete account");
    Console.WriteLine("3.View accounts");
    int card_select = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


     if (card_select == 1){

             Console.WriteLine("\n|  Savings Account  |");
             Saving save1=new Saving("Saving",0);
             save1.Display();

             Console.WriteLine("\n");

             Console.WriteLine("\n|  Debit Card  |");
             Debit deb1=new Debit("Debit",0);
             save1.Display();
             Console.WriteLine("\n");

             Console.WriteLine("|  Credit Card  |");
             Credit cred1=new Credit("Credit");
             cred1.Display();

             Console.WriteLine("\nSuccess, your accounts has been created\n");

         }
```

I tried to add the accounts into a list then print out the account details if the user chooses 3(which i am pretty sure wont work)

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a collection of Type Account object list
2. Add various accounts into that in the main class, provided all different accounts are derived from base account, we can do it
3. Then use that list for selecting objects in a particular index position which user can enter from console. There we have to use the index for a particular object or iterate through the list to find a specific account and use it for display!